# Web2py custom email verification text

Tags: web2py

How to customize the default text on the email verification of Web2py?
Right now it is: Welcome blabla! Click on the link blabla to verify your email.
The link is not a link it is just a text that needs to be copied to the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The various messages presented by the Auth system are in `auth.messages`. For the verification email body, the relevant message is `auth.messages.verify_email`, which defaults to:

```
'Welcome %(username)s! Click on the link %(link)s to verify your email'
```

The format string can include specifiers for any of the registration form fields (e.g., `first_name`, `last_name`, `username`, `email`) as well as the `link` URL (as shown above).

See http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/09/access-control#Auth-Settings-and-messages.